# Python MySQL multi query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm not sure if this is something small that I just cannot see. I'm new to all this SQL in Python and can't see why the transaction is not running in my database. Hope you can help!

```
#requires mysql.connector
import mysql.connector
#make the sql connection
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  db="networks"
)


#create our cursor element
cursor=mydb.cursor()

#lets loop through the table
#run our query to move data in the db to the archive
cursor.execute("""START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO archive select * from data where cdate  < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
DELETE FROM archive WHERE cdate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
DELETE FROM data;
COMMIT;
""", multi=True)

#select all from devices
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM devices")
#do something with this query
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  #Line for testing output from SQL table
  print("Connecting to "+row[1])
  #here is where we run our SSH Code
  #code from here will re-populate the data table

#make sure we close everything
mydb.commit()

cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Wrap the transaction in a try/except block and see if an error is being returned

Comment: Hi. Sorry for this. How would I do this?

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996401/error-handling-in-python-mysql

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Steve tried the try statement. Breaking the connection to the db brought back errors as expected. Running the query with the db connection resolved did not return any errors.

Comment: Well, that's progress of a sort. If you comment out the transaction cursor and run the select cursor only, does that work (assuming there is data in the devices table)?

Comment: @Steve Something I did notice when running the commands outside of the transaction though is that it seemed to perform the delete from data before the insert all from data to archive. Tried commenting out the START TRANSACTION and that seemed to do the same as before.