# Why NAN values while fetching data?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection_str='mysql+pymysql://username:pwd@Host/DB'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)

df = pd.read_sql('select * from tbl_store_inventory', con=db_connection)
print(df)
```

After executing this code, I'm getting NAN value for all the columns. Why?

Comment: are  you sure, that there is a result other then NULL. Please add error handling to your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996401/error-handling-in-python-mysql

Comment: yes iam sure , i've checked in mysql workbench i am getting data there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does tbl_store_inventory look like? If you look at the table in a different program (like a DB IDE), are there entries in the columns?

Comment: hey!  welcome :) You've used read_sql(), I believe this to be a wrapper over read_sql_table and read_sql_query. You've provided a query, from what I understand read_sql()  will then use read_sql_query(). I think this applies less work to properly figure out data types to use. As you are running select * from tbl_store_inventory, perhaps try read_sql_table(table_name ='tbl_store_inventory', con= db_connection)?

Comment: yes there are 4 columns , StoreID, BatchID, Quantity, Location and yes each column has respective data is there

Comment: sir DBAWaffle got the data, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think i was getting NAN values because of read_sql(), i have used read_sql_table() and i got the non-NAN output, when i was using read_sql() for existing values also i was getting NAN, but now after using read_sql_table() for existing values i'm not getting any NAN values.