# SQL Data is fetched only once

Tags: python, mysql, audio-player

I have troubles while fetching data from a SQL-Database. The program gets data from a PHP-site and plays the sound if it is a youtube link. Currently, it has troubles when the database is empty. My goal is, that it exits the for-loop, what it does, but it does not receive any data and tries to fetch it once more until data is inserted by the site.

```
import mysql.connector
import pafy
import vlc
import time
from mysql.connector.errors import Error



url = "NULL"

try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='musicbox',
                                             user='',
                                             password='')
        if connection.is_connected():
                db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                while True :

                        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
                        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)

                        cursor = connection.cursor()
                        print "test2"
                        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM playlist")
                        record = cursor.fetchall()
                        print record
                        time.sleep(1)
                        for x in record:
                                print x[0]
                                if "youtube" in x[0]:
                                        if not all(x):
                                                print "empty"
                                        else:
                                                print "true"
                                                url = x[0]
                                                video = pafy.new(url)
                                                best = video.getbestaudio()
                                                playurl = best.url
                                                Instance = vlc.Instance()
                                                player = Instance.media_player_new()
                                                Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
                                                Media.get_mrl()
                                                player.set_media(Media)
                                                player.play()
                                                time.sleep(1.5)
                                                duration = player.get_length() / 1000
                                                time.sleep(duration)
                                                cursor.execute("DELETE FROM playlist LIMIT 1")
                                                connection.commit()

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: Try doing `connection.commit()` before executing the `SELECT`.

Comment: Also `"DELETE FROM playlist LIMIT 1"` on my database deletes the first record from the target table, which may not be the behaviour that you want.  Something like `cursor.execute("DELETE FROM playlist WHERE url = %s LIMIT 1", (x[0],))` might be better.  Assuming that you want to delete the row after processing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @snakecharmerb your solution with connection.commit() works just fine.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159072/repeated-mysql-queries-from-python/61161279?r=SearchResults&s=5|0.0000#61161279) is an answer that explains what is probably happening.