# Python parse results doesn't match mysql

Tags: python, json, database

I was trying to scrape with python and write to database, i parsed 50 items but when i checked to database shows 16 items. Does anybody knows why and how can i fix that.
Thank you.
Here is my code below:

```
while page < 100:
    try:
        url = ""
        urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        json_obj = json.loads(response.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
        print(json_obj)
        time.sleep(5)
        for product in json_obj["items"]:
            cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO inventory (upc) VALUES (%s)", (product["upc"]))


    except:
        pass
    con.commit()
    page = page + 25
    print(page)
con.close()
```

Comment: If you're ignoring all errors with ``except: pass`` you'll never know why your code fails.

Comment: Take a look at this post! This might help you how to handle error thrown by your database connection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996401/error-handling-in-python-mysql